# C++, how client send list<int> values to server one by one?

Tags: c++, list, tcp, int

Basically, I have a list which contains many different integers, I want to send these data from client to server one value by another?

Comment: You have to be more specific. How do you want to send it? Do you have an established connection with the server? What protocol? Can it be socet or has to webservice.

Comment: I want to send the list<int> through TCP, and I've already get the server and client connected. Now, I need send the list<int> data from client to server. I know the method send() is based on char* or char[]. I don't know how to deal with list<int>. Thank you very much

Comment: you can turn the list of integers into a single string and parse it out on the other side.

Comment: How many integers do you have? It could be good enough to convert int to string (snprintf() f.e) and send each one with send().

Comment: I have 25 different values. I have to send the value one by one to the server. Which method should I use to convert it to string?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, unless it's *absolutely* crucial to send them one by one, you'll nearly always be better off sending an entire list at a time instead.

As to how to send them, you normally want to put the `int`s together into a buffer, convert each to network order, and then send the entire buffer to the receiver. Though I haven't tested this code, something on this general order should work:

```
void send_ints(socket dest, std::list<int> const &in) { 
    std::vector<int> netdata;

    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(netdata), ::ntohl);
    send(dest, (char *)&netdata[0], net_data.size() * sizeof(netdata[0]), 0);
}
```

Depending one your preferences, you might prefer to use `static_cast` instead of the C-style case I've used above.